# Как можно решить такую задачу

Tags: статический-анализ

Существует такая задача. Мы – магазин канцтоваров, выбираем поставщика общих тетрадей, которые будут хорошо продаваться и принесут максимум прибыли. Нужно выбрать только 1 поставщика с несколькими 2-3 наименованиями тетрадей. Как бы вы организовали отбор, имея такие данные? Для решения этой задачи например в Экселе мне не хватает данных о собственно продажах, тогда я бы применил простой абс анализ и все бы стало ясно. [Данные для задачи на Яндекс диске](https://yadi.sk/i/huTW8CsA8Djwzw) Подскажите как ее решить.

Comment: Без данных о влиянии шероховатости и количества страниц на продажи - никак

Comment: Дак а их откуда брать?

Comment: Из маркетинговых исследований, из статистики продаж. Это входные данные для задачи, так что вопрос стоит задать тому, кто вам задачу поставил.

Comment: Ну возможно, тогда зачем в исходных данных выданы критерии оценки и шероховатости.

Comment: У вас в тегах написано названия курса, который преподают в университетах (обычно всем, когда учат на кодеров) так что не поленитесь и зайдите в интернет дабы посмотреть формулы. Вычисления довольно просты, если вы хоть раз работали с матрицами.

Comment: Так вопрос, же в алгоритме, а с матрицами думаю разберемся.